# Accessing variables set in the controller from the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to avoid the use of $scope in my angular controller (*as suggested in a best practices tutorial*). In the controller, I'm setting **testVariable**. In the directive, I'm returning the template, including **testVariable**, but this added variable does not output any value. This code is based on what I've found in the AngularJS documentation.

Below is my javascript code:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      var _controller = this;

      $scope.customer = {
        name: 'Naomi',
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
      };

      _controller.testVariable = "Test Variable!"
    }])
    .directive('myCustomer', function() {
      return {
        template: 'Name: {{customer.name}}<br />Address: {{customer.address}}<br />Value Here: {{ testVariable }}'
      };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-directive-simple-production</title>

    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <div my-customer></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I set up a plunkr for this [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/M21LOiCa55HeIM8LQahQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [controllerAs](https://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/) and `bindToController` it will simplify your directive and then access `testVariable`

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', [function () {
    this.customer = {
      name: 'Naomi',
      address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };

    this.testVariable = "Testing data here!"
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function () {
    return {
      template: 'Name: {{$ctrl.customer.name}}<br />Address: {{$ctrl.customer.address}}<br />Value Here: {{ $ctrl.testVariable }}',
      controller: 'Controller',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      bindToController: true
    };
  });
```

You can further simplify your directive if you use `.component` to create `docsSimpleDirective`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was struggling with. And thanks for the tip with using `.component`.